# Android Studio - Where can I see callstack while debugging an android app?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, callstack

While on a break point, how do I see the call stack to find the callee method/function?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

At the bottom panel you should have "5: Debug". Click on it and select "Debugger -> Threads"

You may need to find the "Threads" icon on the far right, or even click the "Restore Layout" button on the left to restore this window.

[image]

Comment: I see only: { Debugger, Console, Logcat }. Where is "Threads" ?

Comment: Thanks Nickolai, I didn't find "Threads" because I had closed it. I clicked on the icon on the right of the Tabs and I reopened it.

Comment: This took me ages to find and is very counter intuitive.  :(  .  You can turn off the terrible counter intuitive hiding on the settings cog in the extreme top right of the debug window and ensure "Show Views as Tabs" is unchecked

Comment: It may be minimized to the right, find the button with the little arrow pointing at a line (top right corner of the bottom panel) and click it. It will expand again

Comment: i can see the call stack, but how do I see the PC of each frame?

Comment: very nice ! Thank you

Answer (score 155):

Seems like there is an UI-Bug in the Android Studio (1.x, 2.x and 3.x).

For me the "Frames/Threads" Panel was completely hidden behind the toolbar, so I had to change the size from the "variable" panel by dragging its left border to reveal the "Frames/Threads".

[image: Example]

[I have to admit, that **@Greg added this picture** after reviewing my answer!]

Comment: This was the second time I've come across your answer to fix this. Shame i can't upvote for both times!

Comment: @akiller shame that it's still not fixed ;)

Comment: That panel was totally hidden 100%! Thank you for the clear picture!

Comment: Yes, the same dragging out works for me.
How could this happen?  Studio can make it better, right?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of Android Studio. In Android Studio 4.x (screenshot from 4.1.3), it is the camera icon on the left, as seen in the screenshot. Hover over it and you see "Get thread dump", even though it may be counter-intuitive, being more often associated with taking a screenshot.

[image: Android Studio 4.1.3 example]

I just checked Android Studio Dolphin, it is the same button.