# How to see call stack in Android Studio?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio

I read [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071960/android-studio-where-can-i-see-callstack-while-debugging-an-android-app) posts but can not reproduce. So how can I see during debugging the call stack and see which method called the recent method?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Debug Mode` click on `Restore Layout` and you can navigate through `Frames` panel as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [he](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071960/android-studio-where-can-i-see-callstack-while-debugging-an-android-app) wrote, need to drag left side from left to right to open up panel like on screenshoot.

[image]