# Find origin of log message

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am building an Android Accessibility Service. While debbuging it, it shows the following warning:

W/AccessibilityInteractionClient: old interaction Id is: -1,current interaction Id is:372

(The current interaction Id is increasing with 1 for every warning)
AccessibilityInteractionClient is not my message tag and I do not invoke this log message anywhere

I could not find any hints towards the origin of this message nor did I find out what the interaction Id represents.

```
class AccessibilityAutofillService : AccessibilityService() {

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {
        when (event.eventType){
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED -> {
                handleAccessibilityEvent(event)
            }
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED -> {
                handleAccessibilityEvent(event)
            }
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED -> {
                //ignore for now
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
private fun handleAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {
    val packageName = event.packageName
    val root = rootInActiveWindow
    Log.d(_logTag, "event: " + event.eventType + ", package = " + packageName) 
}
```

Log: Warning appears before my log. Warning appears not only for one of my three selected types but probably all accessibility events

```
W/AccessibilityInteractionClient: old interaction Id is: -1,current interaction Id is:232
D/MyTag: event: *someEventType*, package = *somePackageName*
W/AccessibilityInteractionClient: old interaction Id is: -1,current interaction Id is:233
```

Threads:

```
"ADB-JDWP Connection Control Thread"@13'371: WAIT
"AudioThread"@13'073 in group "main": RUNNING
"Binder:11650_1"@12'015 in group "main": RUNNING
"Binder:11650_2"@13'376 in group "main": RUNNING
"Binder:11650_3"@13'359 in group "main": RUNNING
"Binder:11650_4"@12'005 in group "main": RUNNING
"Binder:11650_5"@13'333 in group "main": RUNNING
"Binder:11650_6"@13'379 in group "main": RUNNING
"Chrome_InProcGpuThread"@13'080 in group "main": RUNNING
"Chrome_IOThread"@12'757 in group "main": RUNNING
"Chrome_ProcessLauncherThread"@12'564 in group "main": RUNNING
"CleanupReference"@12'933 in group "main": WAIT
"FinalizerDaemon"@13'372: WAIT
"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon"@13'373: WAIT
"GAC_Executor[0]"@12'858 in group "main": WAIT
"GAC_Executor[1]"@13'206 in group "main": WAIT
"GoogleApiHandler"@12'656 in group "main": RUNNING
"HeapTaskDaemon"@13'374: WAIT
"HwBinder:11650_1"@13'107 in group "main": RUNNING
"JavaBridge"@13'319 in group "main": RUNNING
"Jit thread pool worker thread 0"@13'366 in group "main": RUNNING
"main"@11'995 in group "main": RUNNING
"PlatformServiceBridgeHandlerThread"@12'780 in group "main": RUNNING
"Profile Saver"@11'998: RUNNING
"queued-work-looper"@13'339 in group "main": RUNNING
"ReferenceQueueDaemon"@13'375: WAIT
"RenderThread"@13'108 in group "main": RUNNING
"Signal Catcher"@13'370: WAIT
"TaskSchedulerFo"@13'321 in group "main": RUNNING
"Thread-3"@12'014 in group "main": RUNNING
"Thread-4"@12'019 in group "main": WAIT
```

What is the warning log trying to tell me?

or

How can I find the origin of the log message

Comment: Maybe it can be useful see the stack to intercept the warning cause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071960/android-studio-where-can-i-see-callstack-while-debugging-an-android-app

Comment: How can I use the Threads to find the origin of the warning message?
Since it is connected to the Accessibility Service IMO the relevant Threads are the Binders, Thread-3 and Thread-4.